# Why do table cells appear with delay?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delay, reload

I have a tableviewcontroller. In viewdidload, I call a method which gets some information in josn format from a backend. After receiving my desired response and serialisation, I reload the tableview.
My problem is that the content of the cells will appear within about 30 second delay than table view.
Does any one know how can I fix it?

Comment: Provide some code so that people might know or have some idea on what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reloading tableView on main thread?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.tableView reloadData];        
});
```